# How to close thread when application deactivated?

Tags: multithreading, windows-phone-7, windows-phone, windows-phone-7.1

I have some thread in some page (e.g page1) in wp7. I want to close these thread when the application deactivated in this page, not in the global application file.When application deactivated from some other page only this page onNvavigateFrom is called, bit page1 onNavigateFrom isn't called. How can I do that? Or what is the best practice to close such threads?

Comment: Rolled back.  You can't invalidate Richard's answer by completely changing the question.  Start a new question.

Comment: @Hans Passant I don't change question completely< i only correct my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your thread is the result of using [`BackgroundWorker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker%28VS.95%29.aspx) (the recommended approach), you should be periodically checking [`CancellationPending`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.cancellationpending%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) as described on the [`DoWork`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.dowork%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) documentation.

If you are creating your own Thread, you can emulate this behavior by setting a boolean flag that is checked periodically (in a loop or whatever) by your thread. What you *shouldn't* do is call Thread.Abort as that could leave you with corrupted state if you write to the isolated storage or a database.

Comment: Thanks, I think I will use BackgroundWorker.

Comment: It doesn't work well. When I create some thread in pag1 then I go to page2 the thread is still working< but when I deactivate the application from page2 the exception is occured.Though I change everytime CancellationPending.

Comment: @Aram - The thread has to _complete_, setting CancellationPending isn't enough. What exception are you getting?

Comment: I get these errors: A first chance exception of type 'System.Threading.ThreadAbortException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Threading.ThreadAbortException' occurred in System.dll

Comment: If you want look at my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7620098/how-close-backgroundworker-thread-when-application-is-deactivated